# separate coating of amino acid and vitamin in food suppliment

Tags: prior-art-request, us20100009006, us8361511

Searching for prior art of [US8361511](http://www.google.com/patents/us8361511) .. can any one suggest any document discussing separate coating of amino acid and vitamin followed by another coating used in the food industry?

Comment: Have you done a search for the information you seek? What efforts have you put into looking for this prior art?

Comment: This is looks like a fairly labor-intensive search.  Could you help us by narrowing it down to particular amino acids or vitamins, at least for a starting point?

Comment: Dear Friends, I have searched extensively using various strategy and key strings on TI ...but separate fat based coating of free amino acid and vitamin followed by combine fat coating feature is not available in patent database...i want to know any such reference in non-patent database.

Answer (score 1):

The patent you're referring to might have been anticipated by https://www.google.com/patents/EP1877094A1 "Edible film for transmucosal delivery of nutritional supplements" :

> "**ABSTRACT**   In one embodiment of the present invention a composition
>   is provided comprising a film layer wherein the film layer rapidly
>   dissolves in an oral cavity and a coating comprising a powder matrix,
>   wherein the coating is applied to at least one side of the film layer
>   and wherein the powder matrix comprises a nutritional supplement, an
>   adhesive, a bulking agent, a flow agent, and a sweetener."